# Merge flows into a flow of Triple object kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-flow

I have three flows as follows

```
val flow1 = flow<String> { emit("A") }
    val flow2 = flow<String> { emit("B") }
    val flow3 = flow<String> { emit("C") }
```

I want to merge them to give an object of `flow<Triple>` and my output should be `A B C`

```
merge(flow1, flow2, flow3).collect {
            println(it)
        }
```

I am not getting how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You most probably didn't mean [merge()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/merge.html), but [combine()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/combine.html) or maybe [zip()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/zip.html). `merge()` simply emits items from all upstream flows into the downstream flow. If you need to gather items from all flows and transform them together into another object, you need `combine()` or `zip()`:

```kotlin
val flow1 = flow<String> { emit("A") }
val flow2 = flow<String> { emit("B") }
val flow3 = flow<String> { emit("C") }

combine(flow1, flow2, flow3) { it1, it2, it3 -> Triple(it1, it2, it3) }
    .collect { println(it) }
```

`combine()` and `zip()` differ in a way that the first emits whenever any of upstream flow emits, repeating recent items from other flows. If using `zip()` each item is consumed only once, so we have to wait until both/all flows emit. You need to decide what should happen if e.g. `flow3` emits `C2` - should it generate a `Triple(A, B, C2)` (use `combine()`) or maybe it should wait for further items from `flow1` and `flow2` (`zip()`)?

Answer (score 0):

if you want your output to have an order, you should use flatMapConcat. here is a sample :

```
var merged = flow1
        .flatMapConcat { first ->
            flow2
                .flatMapConcat { second ->
                    flow3.map { third ->
                        Triple(first, second, third)
                    }
                }
        }

    merged.collect { (first, second, third) ->
        print("final result: $first, $second, $third")
    }
```